# how to define URL for custom jquery ajax in Yii

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

I have been writing some ajax request in an external javascript file, finding some difficulties to set the URL. When I check in the console that URL does not reach at controller. I wrote url in ajax as:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'project/projectDelete',
    data: project_id,
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg == 'done') {
            $('.loaderContainer').hide();
            $('#'+projectid).parent().parent().remove();
        }

    }
}); //END $.ajax
```

I got in console the URL request as `http://localhost/example/index.php/cp/project/project/projectDelete`. But it should be `http://localhost/decksgo_new/index.php/cp/project/projectDelete`. Is there any correct way to define URL in ajax in Yii external javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("project/projectDelete") ?>',
    ...
})
```

Comment: I know it, but I wrote ajax in js file.

Comment: use a variable, and define that variable in your layout, and use that variable in that js file

Answer (score 0):

Use CHtml's ajaxLink. Here is untested example that illustrate what I mean!

```
CHtml::ajaxLink("Label", CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('controller/action'),
    array(
        'success'=>'js:function(msg){ }',  //you can use update and replace see CHtml::ajax         
        'type'=>'POST',
        'dataType'=>'json',
        'data'=>array(
            'uid'=>Yii::app()->user->id, //sent to post as $_POST['uid']
            'project_id'=>$data->pid, //sent to post as $_POST['project_id']
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: I know it, but I wrote ajax in js file.

Comment: any reason you did that? To the best of my knowledge that is bad practice that will give you all troubles. So my suggest is you change the design!